# Reward More Reputation to Correct Answers for Up Voted Questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, reputation, upvotes

I was wondering if it were possible to reward more reputation to correct answers for up voted questions.

For example, if a good question had 10 up votes, we could give the person who answers it correctly a slight bonus in reputation.

I feel that those questions generally deserve answers, and it might inspire others to answer them.

Comment: So, in what way will the site benefit from this?

Comment: People who have posted good questions have more people looking to answer them; kind of an incentive for answering good questions.

Comment: You mean... Like giving rep for good answers? (honestly, not trying to pick.... I just don't see the value for the EXTRA incentive)

Comment: [Note question discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322276/what-can-mere-mortal-users-do-to-push-a-feature-request-getting-the-status-de)

Comment: Pouring gas on the fire of voting fraud:(

Comment: Define "answers it correctly"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I feel that those questions generally deserve answers, and it might inspire others to answer them.

But questions that deserve answers usually get them. And those good questions that don't get answers usually don't get them because they're *hard* and the experts who could answer them aren't around.

Extra rep isn't going to change that.

And it's not like good answers don't get upvoted. Nor is there a dearth of upvotes to good answers to hard questions.

This is a solution in need of a problem.

Comment: And where are the experts then?

Comment: @Matsmath: Do you believe that the reason such experts aren't here is that they wouldn't be getting rep fast enough?

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if it were possible to reward more reputation to **correct answers** for up voted questions.

<sup>^ Emphasis mine</sup>

What is a ***correct answer*** actually? The accepted one?

As stated so many times the accepted mark on an answer is the least significance of good quality or correctness.

Sounds weird, but usually the OP is the least person to judge that (otherwise they wouldn't have been asking), but has the privilege to accept as the only user involved.
In the long term view and regarding future research on a particular topic the OP usually doesn't come with the hindsight what's actually useful.

---

1. Good answers are upvoted on judgement by users finding them helpful besides they're accepted by the OP or not.
2. Good questions are upvoted on judgement by users finding them useful to lead for helpful research results, that's mostly independent of the answers and I don't see any reasons why these should earn from question upvotes automatically.

---

> For example, if a good question had 10 up votes, we could give the person who answers it correctly a slight bonus in reputation.

So no, there shouldn't be such feature implemented.

Waiting for mods to mark your request as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

---

<sub>Your [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) just sounds like you're a bit *greedy for gaining extra rep on your answers*.</sub>